# Searching for users/images using MySpace API

Tags: social-networking, myspace

Anyone have an idea about searching for users/images in MySpace using their corresponding APIs ? From the site they told that  by using their API allows you to search for people, videos, images, music.But is it possible now?

Answer (score 0):

it think these wiki might help you
http://wiki.developer.myspace.com/index.php?title=Albums_MySpace_v1

it shows how to fetch user images.cheers !!!